# Google Earth Engine: reproject and rescale bands with different nominal scales

Tags: coordinate-system, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to add bands from various image collections to combine climate data with a dataset of burnt area. I need to export this at a ~1km resolution in GCS WGS84 projection. As the images collections are often different resolutions and projects I am wondering whats the best way to gather them together and export as one image?

Currently, I am specifying the projection and scale on export of the image, but some bands need their resolution reduced, whereas others are becoming a higher resolution. I am not sure whether GEE will be resampling each band correctly (e.g. nearest neighbour is fine for some, but mean resampling is more appropriate for others).

Is there a best practice way to do this, or should GEEs on the fly reprojection/resampling be correct? I have added a simplified version of my code below, in reality many more bands are being added!

```
// set geometry
var geometry =
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[25.276086388357868,50.62278666871328],
          [30.538537560232868,50.43422046631352],
          [31.109826622732868,52.11778572198936],
          [27.561242638357868,52.660871796147255],
          [24.957482872732868,52.687517886257574],
          [23.935754357107868,51.67713311425637],
          [25.276086388357868,50.62278666871328]]], null, false);

// set scale for export use friction layer as template
var statScale_template =  ee.Image("Oxford/MAP/friction_surface_2019")
.select('friction')
.clip(geometry);

print('Template scale: ', statScale_template);

// Function to unmask layer 
//// Unmask layer and clip to geometry
var unmaskClipGeometry = function(image) { 
  return image.unmask()
  .clip(geometry); };

// Filter datasets to correct date

/// CCI image (unmask so masked cells become 0)
var fireCCI = ee.ImageCollection("ESA/CCI/FireCCI/5_1")
.select("BurnDate")
.map(unmaskClipGeometry)
.filterDate('2012-07-01')
.first();

/// MODIS image
var MODISfire = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD64A1")
.select("BurnDate")
.map(unmaskClipGeometry)
.filterDate('2012-07-01')
.first();

/// ERA Climate
var ERAClimate = ee.ImageCollection("ECMWF/ERA5/MONTHLY").filterDate('2012-07-01').first();

// Add bands from images 

var multiBand = fireCCI.addBands(MODISfire)
                      .addBands(ERAClimate);
Map.addLayer(multiBand,"","Multiband image");

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: multiBand.toFloat(),
  description: "test image",
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: statScale_template,
  region: geometry,
  folder: "test data",
  maxPixels: 1e9
});
```